# Number of trees in RandomForest for small sample

Tags: python, tree, random-forest

I have a small sample of 62 observations of two variables (x1,x2)split into Train&Test (70%-30%) hence a very small sample to train a Random Forest model.

I want to predict target  variable y.

Probably silly but was wondering if the number of trees in a RF is directly bound to the dimension of the sample, hence I should set it to 10-20 (which actually works quite well), or I can go with 50-100 trees (which works slightly better in terms of R2, but probably overfitting?)??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer for that but since you have very small amount of data, you should be VERY careful about choosing number of trees and max depth. If you increase both, you will definitely face with overfitting problem therefore you should keep them as lower as possible. So, since the computation is not expensive, you can try different combination of trees and depth and compare train and test errors.